# What should be the handling if accept() system call returns error

Tags: c

If accept system call returns error what is the error handling expected ??
    should we close the socket ??

Comment: Depends on what `errno` holds.

Comment: This question is too broad. Like an embrion asking the doctor "What should I do once I born"...

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the error. On success, `accept()` returns the socket (file descriptor) for the new connection. If it fails, you don't need to close the socket you haven't received (like many system calls, `accept()` returns -1 to signify an error).

Depending on the error code, however, you might decide to close the listening socket.

Comment: I can't think of many examples where `accept` would return an error that would make you want to close the listening socket. The main one I can think of is if you're using a programming style where you just ignore the return value of `socket`, `bind`, and `listen` and rely on `accept` giving you `EBADF` or `EINVAL` if any of the earlier calls failed.

Comment: @R..: It would probably be a policy decision rather than a necessity.  As you say, EBADF and EINVAL would be problems with parameters to the `accept()` call itself, but `EMFILE` might be a reason for shutting up shop (no more file descriptors left for the process).

Comment: Maybe. I would think on `EMFILE` you'd want to just wait for other connections to finish before accepting any more...